# Multiple actions matched when i start controller in asp core

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have asp core Project and Modules project into them

and when i started i cath them - [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6sXd.png)

[Structure of my solution there:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMHVU.png)

how to make it work?

Comment: As you are new here, please allow me one hint: It is very kind of you to say Thank you to some answers, but it would be even kinder to accept the best answer (this is up to you of course!). Voting (once you crossed the 15 rep points yourself) and accepting are the way to say Thx on SO. [Please read this: someone-answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two controllers with the same name, change one of them to another name.

Comment: this is one controller, and this is one folder in same project

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two Actions methods in one controller with the same name, so you need to change the name of one of them . However you can do this if they have different HTTP verbs such as "GET" and "POST"; and in doing so, because they are C# methods, they need to be slightly different. For instance, they could have different parameters. 
For example

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Subscribe()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Subscribe(Subscriber _subscriber)
    {
        ViewData["Title"] = "Subscribe";
        _subscriber.Created = DateTime.Now;
        _subscriber.name= "John Doe";
        _subscriber.email= "JohnDoe@email.com";
        _dataContext.Add(_subscriber);
        _dataContext.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

That should solve the problem.